# nil.to_s Produces a Frozen String?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.7

I'm curious.  Is it surprising that the snippet below yields a `FrozenError`?  The magic comment `# frozen_string_literal: true` is not present.

```
n = nil
s = n.to_s
s.force_encoding('UTF-8')
```

Comment: What version of Ruby? And which line triggers the error?

Comment: I am confused. Why would the presence or absence of `# frozen_string_literal: true` matter?

Answer (score 13):

This was added in Ruby 2.7 -- It's documented explicitly in the [release notes](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/25/ruby-2-7-0-released/).

> `Module#name`, `true.to_s`, `false.to_s`, and `nil.to_s` now always return a frozen String. The returned String is always the same for a given object. [Experimental] [[Feature #16150](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/16150)]

The linked issue has additional reasoning behind the change:

> Much of the time when a user calls `to_s`, they are just looking for a simple string representation to display or to interpolate into another string. In my brief exploration, the result of `to_s` is rarely mutated directly.
>
> It seems that we could save a lot of objects by providing a way to explicitly request a frozen string.
> ...
> This would reduce string allocations dramatically when applied to many common to_s calls.

In summary, it reduces object allocations, which reduces garbage collection overhead, which improves performance.